# Does the result of `bnot` for nonzero integers always flip the sign?

Tags: erlang

Does the result of `bnot` for nonzero integers always flip the sign?

More precisely:

1. Is `bnot NonNeg` where `NonNeg >= 0` always a negative number?
2. Is `bnot Neg` where `Neg =< 0` always a non-negative number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short - yes.

Reason for that is that Erlang uses U2 for encoding negative integers, which mean that `bnot X` is essentially equivalent to `-X - 1`.

Comment: "U2" = "two's complement"?

Comment: Exactly. That mean that negation will always swap sign.

Answer (score 3):

Seems like yes, except for -0. Also, it should be behaving like it does in C.

```
Eshell V11.1.7  (abort with ^G)
1> bnot 1.
-2
2> bnot -1.
0
3> bnot 55.
-56
4> bnot -55.
54
5> bnot 23456789543213456787654323456789765432.
-23456789543213456787654323456789765433
6> bnot -23456789543213456787654323456789765432.
23456789543213456787654323456789765431
7> bnot 0.
-1
8> bnot -0.
-1
9>
```

Comment: There is no negative zeros in Erlang, so `0` and `-0` are exactly the same.